# Hadoop/Swift/Minio... Choosing Large Object Storage solution

Tags: database, blob, minio, openstack-swift

I'm laying out a triple-store centric architecture which is, as you may now, one of the last places in the world you would place large binaries (32mo pictures to ~50-150Go point-clouds and simulation models).

Hadoop performance is well known and documented, but it seems a poor solution in vue of the 50k+ pictures I have to store (small files problems with large 128mb chunks).

Therefore, I may ask for your advice or feedback with openstack-swift, minio or another tech that could suit this need. Notably, I can't use online cloud storages such as the gafam's for diverse reasons :)

Bests ! Thanks for your answers